# vgg16 fine tuning dogs cats fails on testing data

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

So I have been trying to fine tune a VGG16 in order to classify a dataset I made which has 4 classes but while the accuracy on both training and validation sets increased well, the testing would always result in a 25% accuracy no matter what I did. I decided to start first by fine tuning a VGG16 on the cats dogs dataset from Kaggle and I followed different tutorials that got good accuracy results. However, it's the same issue I faced the first time. Now accuracy is 50% (since it's 2 classes). I am starting to think it's a Keras VGG16 problem. I tried all different suggestions online including similar the ones in similar questions in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. All preprocessing, augmentation and layer freezing seem to be done appropriately and after weeks of trial of error I find myself obliged to turn to your suggestions/advice on the matter.

This is the entire code I'm using:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from keras import applications
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import  classification_report,confusion_matrix
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

This next is the confusion matrix function implementation I use.

```python
def plot_confusion_matrix_two(cm,
                          target_names,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=None,
                          normalize=True):

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

accuracy = np.trace(cm) / float(np.sum(cm))
misclass = 1 - accuracy

if cmap is None:
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
plt.title(title)
plt.colorbar()

if target_names is not None:
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(target_names))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, target_names, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, target_names)

if normalize:
    cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]


thresh = cm.max() / 1.5 if normalize else cm.max() / 2
for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
    if normalize:
        plt.text(j, i, "{:0.4f}".format(cm[i, j]),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    else:
        plt.text(j, i, "{:,}".format(cm[i, j]),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")


plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label\naccuracy={:0.4f}; misclass={:0.4f}'.format(accuracy, misclass))
plt.show()
```

Calling VGG16 with imagenet weights and without a top layer + freeze low layers

```python
img_rows, img_cols, img_channel = 224, 224, 3
base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))

for layer in base_model.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

# check the trainable status of the individual layers

for layer in base_model.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)
```

Adding the last layers for classifying our data and compile model:

```python
add_model = Sequential()
add_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
add_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
add_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
add_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
for layer in add_model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False



model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=add_model(base_model.output))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Training parameters, paths etc...

```python
image_size = 224

epochs = 500

train_batch = 50
valid_batch = 30
test_batch = 20

train_dir = 'D:/PetImages/train'
valid_dir = 'D:/PetImages/valid'
test_dir = 'D:/PetImages/test'
```

The data generators for reading from the different sets. The sets are in separate folders so no need for splitting train and valid in my case.

```python
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      #vertical_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=train_batch,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        valid_dir,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=valid_batch,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=test_batch,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True)
```

Training the model:

```python
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_generator.samples // validation_generator.batch_size,
    #callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint('VGG16-transferlearning.model', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)]
    verbose=1
)
```

And then predicting on the test set to compare with ground truth and get the accuracy etc:

```python
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=test_generator.samples//test_generator.batch_size, 
                                      verbose=0)

#Confution Matrix and Classification Report
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')
cm = confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, predictions)
#print(cm)

target_names =['cats', 'dogs']
#target_names =['Bark', 'Jump','Stand', 'Walk']
plot_confusion_matrix_two(cm, target_names, title='Confusion Matrix',cmap=None,normalize=False)

print('Classification Report')
print(classification_report(test_generator.classes, predictions, target_names=target_names))

print('Confusion Matrix')
print(cm)
```

I really tried all different tricks to check. I even tried to check how the model does on the training data itself instead of the testing one and it still gives 50% (which is super weird given that the training accuracy reaches almost 99%). I tried tuning hyper parameters, different algorithms but still nothing changes.

System: Windows 10, Anaconda, Keras 2.1.1 Tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0 Python 3.6.4

Dataset used: https://files.fm/u/t6zdskc7

I've been stuck for weeks now and it's really frustrating. If anyone can help me I'll be forever thankful !!

**Edit:**

So after asking around, it was pointed at me that the model is actually learning and I can check the accuracy of prediction using the following piece of code:

```python
x, y = zip(*(test_generator[i] for i in range(len(test_generator))))
x_test, y_test = np.vstack(x), np.vstack(y)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=64)

print("Accuracy: ", acc)
print("Loss: ",loss)
```

It turns out I do get an actual value that makes sense (around 70% depending on hyper parameters tuning). So my guess now is that something goes wrong when I try to analyze using confusion_matrix and report functions. I still cannot find the issue though.

Comment: Please 1) post a sample of your `predictions` variable *before* the `np.argmax()` operation 2) confirm that your labels are indeed one-hot encoded (as assumed in my answer below)

Comment: It seems like the problem is related to the confusion matrix and classification_report from scikit-learn that I am using. I'm still trying to figure it out though ! Maybe I need to modify the predictions/labels before using them in the function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to classify a dataset I made which has 4 classes

For starters, your network configuration seems strange (to say the least) for a 4-class classification problem; first suggestions:

1. Change to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` in your model compilation
2. Change your last layer to

```python
add_model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

since, due to your `predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)` line, I assume you are already using one-hot encoded labels...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !! In fact, my real purpose is classifying 4 classes, but since the fine-tuning has been failing I tried with the "dogs and cats" dataset on 2 classes and it is still failing. So for now I'm trying to make it work on 2 classes (which explains my configuration). Sorry if my question was not clear

Comment: @OsumanAAA the suggestions still hold; for binary classification, a final layer of either `Dense(2, activation='softmax'))` (for one-hot encoded labels) or `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` is expected...

Comment: Thank you !! I will run again with a "Dense(2, activation='softmax'))" as you suggested and get a sample of predictions as you suggested. It will take some time but I will post when it's done training.

Comment: @OsumanAAA OK, for binary classification leave your `loss='binary_crossentropy'` as is; and on a more general level, since your question already involves *a lot* of code, kindly be sure & consistent regarding the code, the problem, the question etc...

Comment: Since I used Dense(2, activation='softmax')), I thought it made more sense to use loss=''categorical_crossentropy''. Is that wrong? Sure !! Once I try your suggestions I will edit my question again ! thanks a lot !!

Comment: @desernaut I added the newest updates about the problem as an Edit. Please take a look at it if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

**model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=add_model(base_model.output))**
You failed to add new layers correctly. Just use functional API.

```
out = base_model.output
out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dense(256, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(out)
for layer in add_model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)
```

Comment: Are you sure ? I printed the summary of the model and it doesn't look wrong to me.

Comment: I just used your code above, the logical of  adding new layers is obvious wrong, you didn't add dense layers, dropout layers and softmax layer into you modified model.